# Book series about a cyborg space trader

Tags: story-identification

The books followed a space trader who had cybernetic enhancements - he would get heightened reflexes and speed for a short period of time, but had to rest after use to avoid coma. I seem to remember he could use UV vision.

In one of the books a similarly enhanced individual was put on his trail. There was reference to ancient alien tech and reminded me of the *Traveller* role playing game or *Elite*.

I remember reading this in mid-80s.

Comment: @Gallifreian - Nicely edited.

Comment: @Valorum  -  sarcasm? I can never tell.

Comment: Anything else you can add? Language? Country? Cover? How many books in the series? Take a look at [this list](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for some other points you might add.

Comment: @Gallifreian - No, actually nicely edited. I was in the process of basically making all the same changes as you when it popped up to say that it had already been edited. When I clicked it, expecting someone to have just changed the tags, I discovered that you'd done a really decent job of it

Comment: @Valorum  -  oh thank you! Sorry for messing up your edit though...

Comment: I wish my memory was more exact. Vaguely remembered details include the protagonist trying to score big on cargo deals and dealing with his sulky but effective copilot. There were at least three books. Space flight sections very reminiscent of aforementioned role playing game.

Comment: Made me think of Zero Point by Richard Baker which is a StarDrive Novel but doesn't match the date parameter.