# Bio-augmented investigator saved by alien ring when he almost starves due to the energy demands of his body

Tags: story-identification, books

looking for a sci-fi book I read most likely in the 90’s.  Probably not published before the 70’s, certainly not newer than 2000.
Set in the future.

Main character was some sort of private investigator, or law.  Possibly looking for a missing woman or importance?

Was physically biomechanically modified/enhanced. Bio metallic muscle fibers, futuristic Kevlar (cut and bullet/projectile resistant skin, but not resistant to lasers), eyes were “shined” (something like the Riddick character from *Pitch Black* movie/*Riddick* series). Eyes sensitive to UV/IR light, protectors mounted under skin in cheek bones. Retractable silver biomechanic sharp long teeth, claws (both hands and feet). Length of teeth when enhanced hinders his talking. When his “enhanced” mode is triggered, Adrenalin and chemicals flood his body and metabolism races. Massive energy/calorie demands.

One part of the story I remember is he escapes from some sort of captivity (possibly on a space ship) using his abilities (strength claws, etc.). Uses lots of energy, nothing to eat, passes out due to low calories, has some sort of alien artifact ring on his finger at the time. Unknown to him it “heals” him of his injuries and helps him not starve by drawing in the energy from the grass in the clearing in the woods where he passes out in. Wakes up to large brown dead grass circle around him. I think this is all near the beginning of the novel. Wish I had more, thx for the help!

Comment: I think this has been answered here https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230024/book-identification-technologically-enhanced-man-1970s-80s-ya

Comment: That is 100% it. Thank you so much for the info Winchell ! Sorry I couldn’t find it by searching myself. Will look into how to do better searches.

Comment: Not a problem. I have difficulty finding answers here by using the search function myself.

Comment: @slickernu, FYI -- being closed as a duplicate doesn't mean that your question was bad; it just helps to direct future searchers to the answer. Welcome!